# In Anylogic: coordinates of an embedded agent inside an embedded agent

Tags: coordinates, anylogic, agent

How can I get the coordinates of an embedded agent that is inside another embedded agent ?
For example:
I have 2 agents : agent1 and agent2.
Agent 2 is embedded in agent 1.
Agent 1 is embedded in main and rotated.
In main how can I get the coordinates of agent2 the same as the animation of agent2 is shown?

thank you,
Anat.

All the function I found returned the coordinate of the agent relative to it's space agent.

Comment: Did you try to add up the values?
`agent1.getX() + agent1.agent2.getX()`

Comment: Thanks. In my case I also need to manually do a rotation which I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinates are always relative to your parent agent by design. So you need to manually add them up, as Yossi suggested:

`double posX_Agent2 = agent1.getX() + agent2.getX();`

Same goes for rotations.

Comment: thank you I'll do that. I was hoping there was some function inside Anylogic that would  do that for me :-).